# group elements in loop with same ID

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php
$json = '{"name":"Test","id_test":8979,"availability":[{"dateStarts":"2019-12-14","dateEnds":"2019-12-21","dateFormat":"Dec 14 - 21, 2019","length":7,"spaces":5,"program":{"id":2,"title":"Long 2/2","program":"WESTERN ISLANDS"},"rate":{"id":2,"title":"Western Islands Program","prices":[{"custom":true,"defaultPrice":"4845","price":"4545","deck":"all cabins & decks","season":"","cabin":""}]}},{"dateStarts":"2019-12-21","dateEnds":"2019-12-28","dateFormat":"Dec 21 - 28, 2019","length":7,"spaces":"-1","program":{"id":1,"title":"Long 1/2","program":"EASTERN ISLANDS"},"rate":{"id":2,"title":"Eastern Islands Program","prices":[{"custom":false,"defaultPrice":"4845","price":"4845","deck":"all cabins & decks","season":"","cabin":""}]}},{"dateStarts":"2019-12-28","dateEnds":"2020-01-04","dateFormat":"Dec 28 - Jan 04 2020","length":7,"spaces":"-1","program":{"id":2,"title":"Long 2/2","program":"WESTERN ISLANDS"},"rate":{"id":2,"title":"Western Islands Program","prices":[{"custom":false,"defaultPrice":"4845","price":"4845","deck":"all cabins & decks","season":"","cabin":""}]}}]}';    
$request_data = json_decode( $json ); ?>


<select class="select_availability" name="availability"> 
    <?php
    foreach($request_data->availability as $ava){

    if($ava->rate->id == 2){
?>
<optgroup label="<?=$ava->program->program?>">

<option><?=$ava->dateFormat?></option>
</optgroup>
<?php                                                
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

TEST LINK: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gy8f-t3qq

I have a json string that's converted to an array and than I use a `foreach` loop to get all the info, so basically this is the result I get:

```
<select class="select_availability" name="availability"> 
    <optgroup label="WESTERN ISLANDS">

<option>Dec 14 - 21, 2019</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="EASTERN ISLANDS">

<option>Dec 21 - 28, 2019</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="WESTERN ISLANDS">

<option>Dec 28 - Jan 04 2020</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

The output I'm looking for (grouping under the `program` name):

```
<select class="select_availability" name="availability"> 

<optgroup label="EASTERN ISLANDS">

<option>Dec 21 - 28, 2019</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="WESTERN ISLANDS">

<option>Dec 14 - 21, 2019</option>
<option>Dec 28 - Jan 04 2020</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the `$request_data->availability` array before you output your data, and maintain the last `optgroup` label value so that you don't output the same label twice:

```
$request_data = json_decode( $json );
usort($request_data->availability, function ($a, $b) { 
    return strcmp($a->program->program, $b->program->program); 
});
echo '<select class="select_availability" name="availability">' . "\n";
$last_program = '';
foreach($request_data->availability as $ava){
    if($ava->rate->id == 2){
        if ($ava->program->program != $last_program) {
            if ($last_program != '') echo "</optgroup>\n";
            echo '<optgroup label="' . $ava->program->program . '">' . "\n";
            $last_program = $ava->program->program;
        }
        echo "<option>$ava->dateFormat</option>\n";
    }
}
if ($last_program != '') echo "</optgroup>\n";
echo "</select>\n";
```

Output:

```
<select class="select_availability" name="availability">
<optgroup label="EASTERN ISLANDS">
<option>Dec 21 - 28, 2019</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="WESTERN ISLANDS">
<option>Dec 14 - 21, 2019</option>
<option>Dec 28 - Jan 04 2020</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WaAeL)

Note that if the dates in the array might not be sorted for each program, you can modify the sort function to deal with that (and give earliest dates first):

```
usort($request_data->availability, function ($a, $b) { 
    return strcmp($a->program->program, $b->program->program) ?: strcmp($a->dateStarts, $b->dateStarts);
});
```